# LEGO mindstorm EV3 control using FPGA

Tags: ev3, bluetooth

I need advice on this issue. I want to build a communication between EV3 Mindstorms and FPGA. I want to control the different actuator/sensor of the EV3.

The idea is to test functionality of my digital system and its ability to interact with Mindstorms. Interface could be Bluetooth or else.

Could you please give me an idea about this?

Comment: There are a number of questions about the EV3 communication protocol an direct commands already. Perhaps these can be useful to you?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some information on I2C in FPGAs [on fpga4fun](http://www.fpga4fun.com/I2C.html). There are [lots of I2C cores](https://opencores.org/projects) on OpenCores, too. The biggest challenge would be how to connect your FPGA to the peripherals. My advice is to get a tiny development board [like this one](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-1pcs-lot-ALTERA-FPGA-CycloneII-EP2C5T144-minimum-system-development-board-learning-board/1617704540.html?spm=2114.03010208.3.1.mWb1Km&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_10152_10065_10151_10068_436_10136_10137_10157_10060_10138_10155_10062_10156_10154_10056_10055_10054_10059_10099_10103_10102_10096_10169_10052_10053_10142_10107_10050_10051_10084_10083_10119_10080_10082_10081_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10181_10037_10183_10182_10032_10078_10079_10077_10073_10070_10123_10120_10127_10125-10120,searchweb201603_2,ppcSwitch_5&btsid=103647f5-e883-489c-be5f-287a3ec221ff&algo_expid=ab6b1950-58c2-470a-84b9-1d9cce01d7a8-3&algo_pvid=ab6b1950-58c2-470a-84b9-1d9cce01d7a8), and then you need to supply power to it, but this can be battery-powered since FPGAs are typically low-powered.

You would need to make connectors to connect the pins to your MindStorms/PF motors, but that should be fairly easy. However, one concern would be whether the board is able to channel enough power through the pins into the motors: Lego motors are 9V whereas typical FPGA pin output is 5V.